# Looking for a simple trick to solve "how many distinct ways in 14 days are there to go shopping if we must do it either everyday or every 2 days?"

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

Given a question as follows.

> We must go shopping either everyday or every 2 days. How many distinct sequences are there in 14 days? Note that there is an additional constraint where there must be a shopping on the 14th day.

## Attempt

Some possible sequences for illustration purpose only.

- $\{(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12),(13,14)\}$
- $\{(1,2),(3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,9),(10,11),(12,13),(14)\}$
- $\{(1),(2,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,9),(10,11),(12,13),(14)\}$
- $\{(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14)\}$
- etc

Convert the sequence above into the following

- $\{2,2,2,2,2,2,2\}$
- $\{2,1,2,2,2,2,2, 1\}$
- $\{1,2,2,2,2,2,2, 1\}$
- $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$
- etc

It is about partitioning 14 balls into $k$ boxes ($7\leq k\leq 14$) in which each box must contain at least one ball and at most 2 balls.

I translated this problem into finding the sum of coefficients of $x^{14}$ in expanding $(x+x^2)^i$ for $7\leq i\leq 14$. The sum is 610 with the help of Mathematica code below.

```
Table[Coefficient[(x + x^2)^i, x, 14], {i, 7, 14}] // Total
```

My attempt with hand leads to a tedious calculation at the end as follows.

\begin{align}
\text{Required answer} 
&=[x^{14}]\sum_{i=7}^{14}\left(x+x^2\right)^i\\
&=[x^{14}]\sum_{i=7}^{14}x^i\left(1+x\right)^i\\
&=[x^{14}]\left(x^7\left(1+x\right)^7\sum_{i=0}^{7}\left(1+x\right)^i\right)\\
&=[x^{7}]\left(\left(1+x\right)^7\sum_{i=0}^{7}\left(1+x\right)^i\right)\\
&=[x^{7}]\sum_{k=0}^{7}\sum_{i=0}^{7}\sum_{j=0}^{i} {7 \choose k} {i \choose j} x^{j+k}
\end{align}

Does the last triple summation have a simple representation (if there are any identities)?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I don't really understand your comment. Please see my edit to illustrate some legal sequences.

Comment: Is that GF correct?

Comment: What does $x+x^2$ means? And why do you have indices from 7 up only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_n$ means the number of shoppings in $n$ days then we have $a_1=2$ and $a_2 = 3$ and $$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$$ then we found $a_{14}$ in $$2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,...$$
and it is $987$.

---

If we write $0$ for day when we don't go and $1$ when we go we have:

- $n=1$:  $\;\;0$ or $1$;
- $n=2$:  $\;\;11$ or $10$ or $01$;
- $n=3$: $\;\;111$ or $110$ or $101$ or $011$ or $010$

Comment: Do you agree with $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: Why? We can go or not go?

Comment: This is correct, only $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and the element index was counted wrong. This gives 610 indeed

Comment: Do we count not to go also as one way? @doetoe

Comment: @Aqua ah, i see. Then you get 2 indeed, and a2 is 3 in any case as well, sorry! Nice answer btw.

Comment: If we take 3 days instead of 14 days, the answer will be 3 ways which is $a_2$ rather than $a_3= 5$. So $a_n$ must be redefined as the number of shopping in $n+1$ days.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, how can this problem be guaranteed to be Fibonacci sequence with certain initial values only by guessing the first several sequences?

Comment: Note that your answer $a_{14}=987$ is correct if the last day we are allowed not to go shopping and the 13th day we have gone shopping.

Comment: If we go today in shop then on the rest n days we can go on $a_n$ ways and if we dont go then we must go tomorow and on the rest of $n-1$ days we can go on $a_{n-1}$ ways.